# Create random string, check against database, if found run again - Code not functioning as I expected?

Tags: php, mysql

This is somewhat a continuation of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904262/check-a-created-string-against-database-and-if-found-create-new-string/6904405#6904405)

I've taken the following code and somewhat adapted it to my needs;

```
function makeString() {

    // Create our random string
    $string = "";
    $characters = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {

        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, 4)];
    }

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM myTable
    WHERE string = '{$string}'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($row['COUNT(*)'] > 0) { // if it already exists, do it again

        $string = makeString();
    }

    return $string;
}
```

My version:

```
function valCode() {

$num1 = mt_rand(1, 6);
$valcode = $num1;

include("dbdata.php");
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_uname, $db_pword) or die("Couldn't connect because ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name);
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE valcode='{$valcode}'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed because ".mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row['COUNT(*)'] > 0) {
    $valcode = valCode();
}

$query2 = "INSERT INTO records (valcode) VALUES ($valcode)";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die("Query failed because ".mysql_error());

return $valcode;
}

valCode();
```

Rather than creating a random string (an int in the example), checking it against the database, then running it again if found, this runs the script twice, inserting duplicate values into my table.

I thought perhaps this could because of the use of a Primary Key allowing two of the same values to be placed in under different Primary Keys, thus ID'ing them as uniques, but in truth I really have no idea.

Any help or comments would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Prior to PHP 4.2, mt_rand was not automatically seeded.  Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: Also $characters only has 4 positions, but you allow for array indices 0 through 4 to be generated with mt_rand, so you could overflow the array boundary.

Comment: Did you put a unique constraint on the column of "random" values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing what your code says to do. Every call to `valCode()` will execute one `INSERT` query because that's part of the function.

An example run-through of your code:

- You call `valCode()` to start looking for a new code
- `valCode()` generates a code and finds it already exists, so it calls `valCode()` again
- `valCode()` generates a code and finds it already exists, so it calls `valCode()` again
- `valCode()` generates a unique code, `INSERT`s it into the database, and returns to its caller (the second call of the function)
- The second call of `valCode` now `INSERT`s the code and returns to its caller (the first call of the function)
- The first call of `valCode` now `INSERT`s the code and returns to its caller (the end of your code)

You need to move the `INSERT` outside of the function and use its return value in the query.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that the actual place for the insert is inside an `else` so that it's only used if `$valcode = valCode();` isn't called, thus removing the duplicate inserts.